# c++ error c3892 : You can not assign a const variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have one error:
You can not assign a const variable

Class :

```
    class RegChannel {
public:
    std::string channelID;
    std::string pwd;
    DWORD color;
    bool  bActive;

    bool operator < (const RegChannel &r) const {
        return(stricmp(channelID.c_str(), r.channelID.c_str()) < 0);
    }
};

std::set< RegChannel > regChannels;
std::map< std::string, DWORD > savedColor;
std::map< std::string, bool  > savedStatus;
```

Function:

```
        set< RegChannel >::iterator j;
    for( j = chatterUI->regChannels.begin(); j != chatterUI->regChannels.end(); j++ )
    {
       if( stricmp( (*j).channelID.c_str(), channelUI->channelID.c_str() ) == 0 )
        {
            (*j).color = channelUI->channelColor;
        }
    }
```

can you help me please ? (sorry for my bad english...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify the elements stored in a `set`. They are necessarily const. Instead, erase it and insert it again with the modification.

Did you search?

[How to modify object pointed to by iterator from std::set::find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42598763/how-to-modify-object-pointed-to-by-iterator-from-stdsetfind)

[C++ STL set update is tedious: I can't change an element in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/c-stl-set-update-is-tedious-i-cant-change-an-element-in-place)

[what happens when you modify an element of an std::set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908949/what-happens-when-you-modify-an-element-of-an-stdset)